# save special character in Database using Grails

Tags: grails, datasource, special-characters, hsqldb

```
new Trainingcamp(name:"Höhentraining", region:"Alpen").save()
tr1 = Trainingcamp.findByName("Höhentraining")
tr2 = Trainingcamp.findByRegion("Alpen")
println("Tr1: " + tr1?.name)
println("Tr2: " + tr2?.name)
```

Output on console is:

```
Tr1: 
Tr2: H?hentraining
```

So it seems to me that by saving the domainobject something happens that replaces the Special character "ö" with a questionmark "?". How do I get rid of this problem?
Thanks in advanced!

Using Grails 1.3.7

__edit1:
I started the application with prod run-app and then checked the pordDb.log. I found the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO TRAININGCAMP VALUES('H\ufffdhentraining','Alpen')
```

No matter I write an "ö" or "ü or "ä" it allways replace it with "\ufffd"
So, any suggestions to solve this problem?

__edit2:
New insight: The Problem only occur when I save the domain in BootStrap.groovy. By saving the domain in a controller the output on the console is as expected:

```
Tr2: Höhentraining
```

Comment: Have you verified (with other tools) that the character is _actually_ a "?" in the DB? Are you using a proper character set and encoding in the DB?

Comment: I use the grails builtin DB. My dataSource.groovy configuration is: `dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:devDb"
        } ` Where can I change the characterset of the db?

Comment: The character set of HSQLDB is Unicode and stores all possible Java characters. The translation seems to happen in the console.